Rollup nested exports for a private package
I have a private package @company/some-package I am unable to implement nested exports here. For example:

@company/some-package/react
@company/some-package/vue
@company/some-package/vanilla

Exactly like how mui does for import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
I want that users get this treeshakeable design that react actually uses vanilla and we expose all these to users. For me: right now only exports under . are working @company/some-package
Here is my rollup.config.ts  -> https://pastebin.com/u4BkKc7X -> Attached a screenshot of output folder.
Here is my package.json -> https://pastebin.com/TVyDiCx2
Can anyone please help here.
